How to create query shortcut in Visual Studio 2022 like SQL Server
In SQL Server, I can create a query shortcut like select top 10 * from and give assign it to Ctrl+3. When I choose table and press Ctrl+3, the top 10 rows of that table will be shown.
But I can't find this functionality in Visual Studio 2022.
How can I create a query shortcut in Visual Studio 2022?

From looking through the Keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio, i am afraid there is no such query shortcut available in visual studio 2022.
However, i would suggest you submit a feature request from Visual Studio Forum.That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
ps:
I found a VSCode extension mssql for Visual Studio Code that can customize shortcuts. Try to search if there are similar extensions for Visual Studio.(Just an idea.)

i try but cant find the way to do it :(

Maybe you could submit a feature request at Visual Studio Forum to get help.
